# What is the type of the empty list in ML?

Tags: types, sml, ml

I was wondering what exactly the type of the empty list is in SML (I'm using PolyML)?
When I type `[]` into the interpreter, I get out:

```
val it = []: 'a list
```

which is what I would expect. But then, if I were to type in say:

```
fun f a = if a = 0 then [] else [[]];
```

then I get:

```
val f = fn: int -> 'a list list
```

which would seem to imply that `[]` has the type `'a list list` also. How exactly does this work?

Comment: Is your confusion specifically that there's still an `'a` in the final type or would you have the same problem with `if a = 0 then [] else [1]` where the type of `[]` suddenly becomes `int list`?

Comment: Yes I see what you mean - I guess my confusion arose because I was viewing the two type signatures simultaneously - i.e. I mistakenly thought that the `'a` in the first type must be the same as the `'a` in the second type signature - but it all makes sense now, thanks :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ML terminology, a value has a *type scheme*, not a type. A type scheme is a collection of types. It's a type with wildcards, and the wildcards can be replaced by any type. Replacing the wildcards by types is called *instantiating* the type scheme.

In `'a list`, `'a` is a type variable, i.e. a wildcard. The empty list `[]` can be used at any type that is an instance of the type scheme `'a list`. That is, for any type `T`, the empty list has the type `T list`. For example, the empty list has the type `int list` and the type `bool list` and the type `(int * int * int) list` and the type `int list list` and so on. All of these types are instances of the type scheme `'a list`.

When a variable occurs multiple times, it must be replaced consistently. For example `fn x => x` (the identity function) has the type scheme `'a -> 'a`; it has the type `int -> int` and the type `bool -> bool` but not the type `int -> bool`. A value with the type scheme `'a -> 'b` would have the type `int -> bool` as well.

A value can have multiple types — this is a common phenomenon in programming languages. It is a property of the core ML language that the set of types of a well-typed value is exactly the set of instances of a type scheme. This property is called *principality*: the type system of ML is principal. Concrete implementations of ML tend to have exceptions to principality; for example SML has an exception due to the overloading of operators (`fn x => x + x` has the two types `int -> int` and `float -> float`, and the overloading resolution rules cause the compiler to decide on `int -> int` if the context does not impose `float`).

A value whose principal type scheme contains at least one variable is said to be *polymorphic*. A value whose principal type scheme does not contain variables is said to be *monomorphic*.

A wildcard can be replaced by a type scheme. This yields another type scheme which is a subset of the original collection, i.e. the type scheme is a smaller type scheme (a refinement) of the original. For example the value `[[]]` has the type scheme `'a list list`: it has the type `T list list` for any type `T`. `[[]]` has the type `int list list` and the type `bool list list` and the type `(int * int * int) list list` etc.

In literature about ML, “type” is often used interchangeably with “type scheme”, so it's usual to say that “the empty list has the type `'a list`”. In literature about type systems, “type” often means what ML terminology calls “type scheme”, and other terms such as “ground type” are used for a type without variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarifying terminology!